# gradle copy task is scanning all into files

Tags: gradle

If I have a simple gradle file that contains

```
task mytry(type:Copy){
   from '/tmp/try'
   into '/tmp'
}
```

and I have a file /tmp/try/1.txt
I expect this to copy /tmp/try/1.txt to /tmp/1.txt

However, it scans all of /tmp  (the into param) before doing the copy.
There are files in /tmp (such as /tmp/.X11-unix/X0) that gradle cannot access, and so it fails.

How to I tell the copy task to not scan the into directory?

I've tried 'include'  'exclude **'

(This is an example of my real problem, the real issue is that in my project the 'into' is a massive directory with many subdirectories and gradle is scanning every single file which takes forever)

gradle version 1.12 (v2 is not an option yet)

Comment: I've tried to resolve this, but still getting the full directory scan. Anyone have any ideas? Or is this a bug?